# If/Switch/Case or simple Boolean arithmetic in SELECT statement in HQL/SQL

Tags: boolean, mapping, case, hql, coalesce

I'm searching for an elegant solution to the following problem:
I have a table with some data which is classified by a column *ok* (boolean). If *ok* is true then the data is valid if false then not.

Now I have a parameter *filterOff* (boolean) which should do the following: 
If it is set to true then it should ignore the column *ok* (or search for both ok = TRUE and ok = FALSE) and return all rows. If it is set to false then it should only return those rows for which ok = true. If it is not set (equals NULL) then it should behave the same way as if it would be false.

**Conditions**

```
1. filterOff == NULL OR filterOff == FALSE => ok = TRUE

2. filterOff == TRUE => ok = TRUE OR ok = FALSE
```

For the 1st I would use sth like this:
`ok <> COALESCE(filterOff, FALSE)`

However it is missing the `ok = FALSE` part in the 2nd condition.

Anybody able to help? Thanks in advance!

Best regards

IceThunder

Answer (score 0):

```
(COALESCE(filterOff, FALSE) AND TRUE) OR ok = TRUE
```

That's it.